# Replacing text in data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to replace text in one column with numbers

for example,

```
>df = chickwts
>df
   weight      feed
1     179 horsebean
2     160 horsebean
3     136 horsebean
4     227 horsebean
5     217 horsebean
6     168 horsebean
7     108 horsebean
8     124 horsebean
9     143 horsebean
10    140 horsebean
11    309   linseed
12    229   linseed
...
```

How do I replace all 6 feed names with the numbers `1:6` in one command?

I am a beginner in r and spent an hour trying different functions with no success. I want to use

```
fr = unique(df$feed)
to = 1:6
```

But beyond that, I am having difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends what you want to do. If you are planning on doing some statistical analysis that treats feed as a categorical variable then `as.factor` is what you are looking for. Try this:

```
#  Turn them into a factor like this
df$feed <- as.factor( df$feed )

#  Here are the levels of the factor
levels( df$feed )
# [1] "horsebean" "linseed" 

#  If you want their underlying numerical values
as.numeric( df$feed )
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

Comment: so just to add on to SimonO101:

`df$feed <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$feed))`

would do what you want